# How create rest api for send message with ssh tunnel in golang?

Tags: go, ssh, ssh-tunnel

**i want to build an ssh server to communicate with ssh client.**

so, i wanna build two of rest api server, Server A as Host, and Server B as Client.
Assume server A is behind firewall and server B is not, then, i wanna build ssh tunnel for communication between A and B within this tunnel.

when A is active and enters ip addres B, then A can send emails or messages, including A's own ip addres to B. after B gets A's ip addres, server B will send message to A.

can anyone explain step by step to build ssh tunnel like this with golang? if there is, I ask for references to make the code?? thank you

Comment: port 22 is open by default. You can use it. Also port 80.
You don't have to deal with a firewall. If you use closed ports than open them.
Another thing is you don't have to make your applications communicate over ssh. You can make it communicate via whatever protocol you find easiest. http tcp websocket etc.
Finally there is an easy ssh library that will help. https://github.com/melbahja/goph

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an SSH tunnel in bash and point your script to it. However:
You may need to write scripts that are too complicated for bash.
It can make your scripts brittle if you need to run multiple tunnels or forget to clean them up for long running processes.
You may not have access to a separate terminal to run the SSH tunnel such as under some automation script.
Want to use all your existing Go code, but bolt on the tunnel.
Dislike bash.
Well, here you go. The following code supports creating multiple hassle-free SSH tunnels in pure Go and support using a private key or password authentication:

```html
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)
type Endpoint struct {
    Host string
    Port int
    User string
}
func NewEndpoint(s string) *Endpoint {
    endpoint := &Endpoint{
        Host: s,
    }
    if parts := strings.Split(endpoint.Host, "@"); len(parts) > 1 {
        endpoint.User = parts[0]
        endpoint.Host = parts[1]
    }
    if parts := strings.Split(endpoint.Host, ":"); len(parts) > 1 {
        endpoint.Host = parts[0]
        endpoint.Port, _ = strconv.Atoi(parts[1])
    }
    return endpoint
}
func (endpoint *Endpoint) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", endpoint.Host, endpoint.Port)
}
type SSHTunnel struct {
    Local  *Endpoint
    Server *Endpoint
    Remote *Endpoint
    Config *ssh.ClientConfig
    Log    *log.Logger
}
func (tunnel *SSHTunnel) logf(fmt string, args ...interface{}) {
    if tunnel.Log != nil {
        tunnel.Log.Printf(fmt, args...)
    }
}
func (tunnel *SSHTunnel) Start() error {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", tunnel.Local.String())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer listener.Close()
    tunnel.Local.Port = listener.Addr().(*net.TCPAddr).Port
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        tunnel.logf("accepted connection")
        go tunnel.forward(conn)
    }
}
func (tunnel *SSHTunnel) forward(localConn net.Conn) {
    serverConn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", tunnel.Server.String(), tunnel.Config)
    if err != nil {
        tunnel.logf("server dial error: %s", err)
        return
    }
    tunnel.logf("connected to %s (1 of 2)\n", tunnel.Server.String())
    remoteConn, err := serverConn.Dial("tcp", tunnel.Remote.String())
    if err != nil {
        tunnel.logf("remote dial error: %s", err)
        return
    }
    tunnel.logf("connected to %s (2 of 2)\n", tunnel.Remote.String())
    copyConn := func(writer, reader net.Conn) {
        _, err := io.Copy(writer, reader)
        if err != nil {
            tunnel.logf("io.Copy error: %s", err)
        }
    }
    go copyConn(localConn, remoteConn)
    go copyConn(remoteConn, localConn)
}
func PrivateKeyFile(file string) ssh.AuthMethod {
    buffer, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    key, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    return ssh.PublicKeys(key)
}
func NewSSHTunnel(tunnel string, auth ssh.AuthMethod, destination string) *SSHTunnel {
    // A random port will be chosen for us.
    localEndpoint := NewEndpoint("localhost:0")
    server := NewEndpoint(tunnel)
    if server.Port == 0 {
        server.Port = 22
    }
    sshTunnel := &SSHTunnel{
        Config: &ssh.ClientConfig{
            User: server.User,
            Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{auth},
            HostKeyCallback: func(hostname string, remote net.Addr, key ssh.PublicKey) error {
                // Always accept key.
                return nil
            },
        },
        Local:  localEndpoint,
        Server: server,
        Remote: NewEndpoint(destination),
    }
    return sshTunnel
}
```

Here is an example of usage:

```html
func main() {
   // Setup the tunnel, but do not yet start it yet.
   tunnel := NewSSHTunnel(
      // User and host of tunnel server, it will default to port 22
      // if not specified.
      "ec2-user@jumpbox.us-east-1.mydomain.com",
      // Pick ONE of the following authentication methods:
      PrivateKeyFile("path/to/private/key.pem"), // 1. private key
      ssh.Password("password"),                  // 2. password
      // The destination host and port of the actual server.
      "dqrsdfdssdfx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439",
   )
   // You can provide a logger for debugging, or remove this line to
   // make it silent.
   tunnel.Log = log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.Ldate | log.Lmicroseconds)
   // Start the server in the background. You will need to wait a
   // small amount of time for it to bind to the localhost port
   // before you can start sending connections.
   go tunnel.Start()
   time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
   // NewSSHTunnel will bind to a random port so that you can have
   // multiple SSH tunnels available. The port is available through:
   //   tunnel.Local.Port
   
   // You can use any normal Go code to connect to the destination
   // server through localhost. You may need to use 127.0.0.1 for
   // some libraries.
   //
   // Here is an example of connecting to a PostgreSQL server:
   conn := fmt.Sprintf("host=127.0.0.1 port=%d username=foo", tunnel.Local.Port)
   db, err := sql.Open("postgres", conn)
   // ...
}
```